# Unity & Daydream - Stream videos from youtube

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, daydream

How would I go about adding youtube video to a unity project?

Im playing around with Google's Daydream and have setup the video example:

https://developers.google.com/vr/video/video-overview

The next thing I would like to do is play a video from youtube.

What would be involved in doing this?

I can see other people are doing it for example: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/29704

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an "official" way to do this right now.

Take a look at YouTubeExtractor (https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor) to see what would be involved - although this only handles the download, not really the streaming component.

-Tom